# Example of a ternary $C^{\ast}$-ring which is not an operator space

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

A ternary $C^{\ast}$-ring  is a complex Banach space $X$, equipped with a ternary product $[\cdot,\cdot,\cdot]:X^3 \to X$ which is linear in outer variables and conjugate linear in middle variable. Also $X$ is associative i.e.  $$[[a,b,c],d,e]=[a,[d,c,b],e]=[a,b, [c,d,e]].$$  Moreover, $\lVert[a,a,a]\rVert= \lVert a\rVert^3$ and $\lVert[a,b,c]\rVert \leq \lVert a \rVert \lVert b\rVert\lVert c\rVert$.

> Does there exist a ternary $C^{\ast}$-ring which is not an operator space?

One obvious class of examples of ternary $C^{\ast}$-rings is the class of  ternary rings of operators but they all are operator spaces.

Comment: Is the middle condition in the definition of associativity really supposed to have $b$ and $d$ switched?

Comment: @LSpice: Yes. These are also known as ternary algebras of 2nd kind. In $1$st kind the associativity condition is the natural one.

Comment: Your question is not well posed because any Banach space can be realized as an operator space, via the MIN or MAX constructions

Comment: @YemonChoi, can [those](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407250/example-of-a-ternary-c-ast-ring-which-is-not-an-operator-space#comment1044391_407250) constructions be made to respect the ternary operation?

Comment: @LSpice I don't know off the top of my head, **but that was not the question which was asked**. As with some of the OP's history of questions, I start to find the lack of precision troubling.

Comment: @LSpice The point is that an "operator space", in the widely understood sense, does not have any intrinsic multiplication or any ternary operation defined on it. Hence the question that was asked is a bit like asking if there is any semigroup which is not a subset of aleph_2

Comment: @YemonChoi, when the OP refers to an "operator space" in the context of ternary C*-rings, they mean a closed subspace  $X\subseteq B(H)$ such that $XX^*X\subseteq X$, and equipped with the ternary product $$[x,y,z]=xy^*z.$$

Comment: @MathLover Would it be possible for you to edit your question, and make it a bit clearer as to what is being asked?  My personal reading of the question currently is that the example Ruy speaks of is a "ternary ring of operators" which is _not_ all possible examples of an "operator space" (and thus you are asking something more general than Ruy's answer).  But I cannot be sure.

Comment: @YemonChoi In light of Ruy's response, might there be a way of making the question precise to your satisfaction? It sounds like OP is saying: I don't know of any examples of ternary $C^\ast$-rings except the ones of Ruy's form (up to isomorphism).

Comment: @MatthewDaws: I was basically looking for an canonical embedding of ternary $C^*$-ring in a $C^*$-algebra like we have for TROs by means of linking $C^*$-algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Zettl [1], a *ternary ring of operators* (TRO) is a
ternary $C^*$-ring which is isomorphic to a closed
subspace $X\subseteq B(H)$, such that $XX^*X\subseteq X$, equipped with the ternary multiplication
$$
  [x,y,z] := xy^*z.
  $$
On the other hand, an *anti-TRO* is a ternary $C^*$-ring defined as above, except that the multiplication operation is
$$
  [x,y,z] := -xy^*z.
  $$
It is a fundamental result of Zettl [1] that every ternary $C^*$-ring $X$ decomposes uniquely as
$$
  X=X_+\oplus X_-,
  $$
where $X_+$ is a TRO, and $X_-$ is an anti-TRO .

It seems to me that the reading of the question posed by the OP that makes the most sense is by taking the expression
"operator space" to mean a TRO.  In this case the answer is yes, there does exist a ternary $C^*$-ring which is not a
TRO: just take any non-zero anti-TRO.  For an even more concrete example, take $X=M_{n\times m}({\bf C})$, with ternary
multiplication $[x,y,z] := -xy^*z$.

On the other hand, if one takes the expression "operator space" for its face value, Zettl's result implies that every
ternary $C^*$-ring is an operator space in an even more canonical form than suggested by user @YemonChoi: write
$X=X_+\oplus X_-$, embedd $X_+$ in $B(H_+)$, and $X_-$ in $B(H_-)$, whence
$$
  X\subseteq B(H_-\oplus H_+).
  $$
This embeding preserves the operator space structure (norms on matrix algebras) that a TRO canonical possesses.

It is interesting to remark that if you change the (binary) multiplication operation on a $C^*$-algebra by
$$
  x\circ y := -xy,
  $$
then the resulting object is strictly speaking a new C*-algebra, but it is isomorphic to the old one.  The isomorphism
is simply $a\mapsto -a$.

However, if you change the (ternary) multiplication on a ternary $C^*$-ring by inserting a minus sign as above, then the
map $a\mapsto -a$ is no longer an isomorphism,  essentially because 2 is even and 3 is odd!
Indeed, Zettl's uniqueness result tells you that the new ternary $C^*$-ring
might not be isomorphic to the old one at all!

---

EDIT: Here are some details of Zettl's proof which might shed some light into the reason an anti-TRO not isomorphic to a TRO.

Given a ternary $C^*$-ring $X$, let $A$ be the closed linear span within $B(X,X)$ (bounded operators on $X$) of the set
of operators of the form
$$
  T_{y, z}:x\in X\mapsto  [x,y,z]\in X,
  $$
as $y$ and $z$ range in $X$.  It is easy to see that $A$ is a Banach algebra, and Zettl proves that $A$ is indeed a
$C^*$-algebra for a unique involution operation "$^*$" satisfying
$$
  T_{y, z}^* = T_{z, y}.
  $$

Given this, it is clear that an operator of the form $T_{y,y}$ is self-adjoint but the key question is whether or not
this is moreover positive.

If $X$ is a TRO, then $T_{y, y}\geq 0$, while in the anti-TRO case, one has that $T_{y, y}\leq 0$.

In other words, the positivity of $T_{y, y}$ is a signature of TRO's not shared by their anti-TRO cousins.

[1] *Zettl, Heinrich*, [**A characterization of ternary rings of
operators**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(83)90083-X), Adv. Math. 48, 117-143
(1983). [ZBL0517.46049](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0517.46049).

Comment: Is it clear that this does not embed in some (possibly different) operator algebra?  Maybe this is what you mean by decomposing uniquely into a positive part and a negative part, but I don't know what that means.

Comment: @WlodAA, [thanks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407250/example-of-a-ternary-c-ast-ring-which-is-not-an-operator-space/407306#comment1044509_407306)!  I have deleted my wrong comments about parity.

Comment: @LSpice, I've edited my answer hopping to clarify my point.  Indeed my original answer was a bit terse!

Comment: Thanks!  This definitely makes clear that you might obtain a new algebra from the old one in a particularly simple fashion.  But is it clear that this new, different algebra does not embed in some new, different operator algebra?  I think I must be misreading your description, because it seems to me that you are saying that every ternary $C^*$-ring *does* embed in an operator algebra in a particularly rigid way.

Comment: @LSpice,  the last paragraph in my latest edit might help one to see what is wrong with anti-TRO's.

Comment: @Ruy: Thank you very much for an informative answer.  Do you  any notion of “linking $C^*$-algebra” for Ternary $C^*$-rings like we have for TROs? Zettl’s $C^*$-algebra  does not quite qualify to be “linking $C^*$-algebra” as two non isomorphic ternary $C^*$-rings also can have isomorphic $C^*$-algebras.

Comment: @MathLover, I don't think there is a meaningful linking C*-algebra for an anti-TRO $X$.  If there was one, then that algebra would embedd into $B(H)$, and hence so would $X$, but we know $X$ cannot be  represented in $B(H)$ (unless you are willing to disregard its ternary product).